# Access Google spreadsheet from Google Appengine with service account : working once per hour

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have implemented the python code here below based on the documentation in order to access a spreadsheet accessible through a public link.
It works once every hour. If I execute a few seconds after a success, I receive an error :

```
Error opening spreadsheet no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Assumption:
The access token has an expiry date of 1 hour. So the appengine would proceed to a token refresh after an hour, resetting the whole.

Question:
This code requests a new token for each request. So what should I do ? Save the token ? When I try the token_to_blob in order to save the token, I get an error :
    Scope undefined

Thanks in advance for your help !

```
    try :
        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://docs.google.com/feeds'))
        logging.info("credentials")
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        authclient = build('oauth2','v2',http=http_auth)
        auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
    except Exception as details:
        logging.error("Error Google credentials %s"%details)
        return "Error"

    try :
        gd_client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
        gd_client = auth2token.authorize(gd_client)
        feed = gd_client.GetListFeed(<spreadsheetKey>,1)
    except Exception as details:
        logging.error("Error opening spreadsheet %s"%details)
        return "Error"
```

Comment: Have a look at gspread, which makes it very easy to access a spreadsheet using a sevice account.

Comment: Can you first identify where the error 'no element found' is coming from? Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920529/python-problems-accessing-a-google-spreadsheet-using-an-oauth-2-0-service-clie) and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks - No element found comes from empty answer due to wrong authentication parameters, even if the spreadsheet is public

Answer (score 1):

I finally declared the credentials & the token as global.
In this case, it was working for several subsequent requests but after 1 hour, the token was invalid.

I tested with the method access_token_expired but this method always returned false.

So, I finally execute the refresh systematically and it works. Not elegant but functional. Another option would be to store the time of next refresh and only refresh after 1 hour.

Your comments are welcome for elegant alternatives.

I did not try gspread since the rest of the code was already functional for gdata.spreadsheets but perhaps I should.

```
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from oauth2client.client import Credentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2

global credentials
global auth2token
try :
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://docs.google.com/feeds'))
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    authclient = build('oauth2','v2',http=http_auth)
    auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
except Exception as details:
    logging.error("Error Google credentials %s"%details)

class importFromSpreadsheet(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __importFromSpreadsheet(self,u):
        try :
            credentials._refresh(httplib2.Http())
        except Exception as details:
            logging.error("Error refreshing Google credentials %s"%details)
...
        try :
            gd_client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
            gd_client = auth2token.authorize(gd_client)
            feed = gd_client.GetListFeed(u,1)
        except Exception as details:
            logging.error("Error opening 1st spreadsheet %s"%details)
            return "Error"
```